# Show msg instead of user's input

Tags: c++

I'm new in this forum and English is not my first language

here's my question

i wanna create a program that get integer input from user then clear this value from the screen and show msg instead of value

for example

```
cin>>n;                                 // 10
cout<<"hello world";
```

when i run this program it show output like this

```
 10
 hello world
```

i want this 10 to be removed and screen show just

```
 hello world
```

please help me thanks

Comment: You mean you want to switch off your terminals' echo feature, or immediately clear the last recent line after input?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> 10
> hello world
> ```
>
> *"i want this `10` to be removed and screen show just"*
>
> ```
> hello world
> ```

Unfortunately this cannot be solved just using C++ standard I/O facilities, because it heavily depends on your actually used terminal and its control character implementation options.

The default behavior of terminals is to *echo* the characters typed in from the user. Some terminal implementation allow you to control to hide the typed in characters (*switch off echo*). Alternatively you may have options to remove typed in characters using a backspace, or so.

If your current terminal supports these, there are basically 2 options:

1. You switch off the input *echo mechanism*, before calling `cin>>n;`
2. You immediately clear the last input made by `cin>>n;`, e.g. outputting the `'\b'` backspace character

Comment: @WajidMax What exactly didn't you understand from my answer?

Comment: If you use Linux/UNIX, you can use [ANSI escape codes](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/c327.html) and do `std::cout << "\033c" << std::flush;` to clear the screen. But, as @πάνταῥεῖ mentioned, this is not a portable solution (i.e., most likely won't work on Windows/other platforms).

Comment: I'm want to clear input made by cin>>n; I'm using turbo cpp for window xp

Comment: @WajidMax my advice is to get rid of TurboC++ ASAP, and replace it with MinGW or Cygwin. Start using some proper C++ compiler, not antiquities built even before C++ was standardized.

Comment: i know  its too old but its part of my studies